# How do I generate ctags for CoffeeScript?

Tags: vim, coffeescript, ctags

Is it possible to generate a ctags file for CoffeeScript in vim/MacVim?

Comment: This should really be tagged [coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coffeescript), not [coffee](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coffee), n'est pas? :)

Comment: I had originally meant to tag it coffeescript but it seems there was a hiccup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native support for [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sf.net), but if you just want to gather some variable and function definitions, you can create your own rules.

[Here is an example](http://gist.github.com/907245) that appeared in a google search.

Answer (score 24):

I released a tool which gives you what you need - [coffeeTags](https://github.com/lukaszkorecki/coffeetags)

Comment: Do you think it's possible to use with CTags plugin for Sublime Text 2 (https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags)? I can't get it working together. Probably there is some format differencies?

Comment: @okonetchnikov - sorry for ignoring your comment! SO's notification system is still a bit of a mystery ;-) As for your question: `extra_tag_files` option gives you the ability to specify additional ctags file. So lets say you set it to 'coffeescript.tags' and then you can use CoffeeTags to generate CoffeeScript tags with `coffeetags -R . > coffeescript.tags`. I don't use ST2 myself to it's a bit of a guess work. Let me know if that works and I will include this in CoffeeTag's readme

Comment: @okonetchnikov - yes, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edubkendo/2901380).

Comment: I think it's not more relevant since ST3 has its own code analysis which works quite good for CS as well. But thanks!